# Expect assertion that is only true for one element in an array

Tags: ruby, rspec

I want to assert that an array contains at least one element that passes an RSpec expectation. But most of the elements in the array will not pass the expectation. So I'd like to do something like this:

```
it "finds one element that matches" do
  array.any? do |element|
    expect(element).to eq("expected value")
  end
end
```

And have the test pass if any of the elements pass the expectation. But, of course, the test will fail as I've written it here.

Is there a pattern in RSpec to do what I want to accomplish?

---

I don't want to do this:

```
it "finds one element that matches" do
  expect(array.any? {|val| val == "expected value"}).to be_true
end
```

Because it's not clear to me how to manually check the same thing as the matcher I need to use in my test. I want to use the `have_attributes` matcher, which does some [subtle metaprogramming magic](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/lib/rspec/matchers/built_in/have_attributes.rb#L96) I don't want to risk messing up trying to re-implement on my own.

Comment: I don't believe there is a built in method that passes a test if other specs fail. Have you thought about assigning a varaible as false at the start, switching it to true if any of your array elements match your requirement, and then testing at the end if the variable has been set to true?

Comment: @Mark Yes. The second half of my question explains why I'd rather not do that if possible.

Comment: `expect` doesn't return a useful value `any?` can operate on. Your second form is a lot more clear., but `array.include?("expected value")` is the more minimal form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RSpec has [composing matchers](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-8/docs/composing-matchers) that can be used with `expect(array).to include` to achieve what I wanted. For example:

```
expect(array).to include(a_string_matching("expected value"))
```

For the `have_attributes` matcher specifically, RSpec has an alias for it called [`an_object_having_attributes`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-expectations/RSpec/Matchers#an_object_having_attributes-instance_method), allowing me to write:

```
expect(array).to include(an_object_matching(object_i_want_duplicated))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `include` matcher to [compose matchers](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-8/docs/composing-matchers#composing-matchers-with-%60include%60):

```
expect(array).to include(a_string_matching(/foo/))
```

Despite the somewhat awkward syntax, you can use this with `have_attributes`:

```
expect(obj).to have_attributes(tags: include(a_string_matching(/foo/))
```

But if that's not flexible enough for whatever reason, you can use the `satisfy` matcher:

```rb
expect(array).to satisfy {|arr| arr.any? {|val| val == "expected value"})
```

The double-nested block is somewhat awkward by itself, but the flexibility of satisfy lets you do all kinds of stuff with it, and you can use the `include` matcher to get you there. For example:

```rb
require "rspec"
require "ostruct"

obj = OpenStruct.new(name: "foobar", tags: %w(bin bazzle))

describe obj do
  it "has a bin tag" do
    is_expected.to have_attributes(tags: include(/bin/))
  end

  it "has a tag 3 characters long" do
    is_expected.to have_attributes(tags: include(satisfy { |t| t.length == 3 }))
  end
end
```

If you're willing to add a gem, I really like [rspec-its](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-its) for cases like these: they can clean up the specs for individual attributes of an object which don't warrant their own subject block nicely:

```rb
describe obj do
  its(:tags) { is_expected.to be_a Array }
  its(:tags) { is_expected.to include "bin" }
end
```

Comment: This is close to what I was looking for, I did need to use a composable matcher. But I eventually found the [`an_object_having_attributes` matcher](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-expectations/RSpec/Matchers#an_object_having_attributes-instance_method), allowing me to use the approach I went with in my answer. Your first example lets me assert that an array contains the string I'm looking for, but I don't see how any of your other examples let me assert that an array contains an object with the attributes I want?